# how does base order affect the change of coordinate matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

i am considering two bases. i need to find the change of coordinate matrix that changes $B'$ coordinates into $B$ coordinates.

my first question had these two bases.

$B=\{x^2,x,1\}, B'=\{a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0,b_2x^2+b_1x+b_0,c_2x^2+c_1x+c_0\}$

my answer was $
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\
    a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\
    a_0 & b_0 & c_0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$ and it was correct.

in the second problem, $B'$ was the same as before, but now $B=\{1,x,x^2\}$.

i got the same answer as before because when i turn each element of $B'$ into a linear combination of this definition of $B$, i think that the coefficients of the linear combination are the same as the ones for each element of $B'$. i.e., $a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0=ax^2+bx+c\mapsto a_2=a,a_1=b,a_0=c$.

but the answer for this question is the same as above with the first and third rows switched. (i.e., $a_2$ row on the bottom, $a_0$ row on the top. the answer i got is incorrect.)

how does the order of $B$ affect this matrix?

thank you in advance for any insight.

Comment: Consider a change of basis matrix from $\{x^2,x,1\}$ to $\{1,x,x^2\}$. What do you get?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the two bases are the same, since they’re presented via set notation, which is order-agnostic. Unfortunately, this is a common notational practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It affects because you have to write, say, the first element of $B'$ as$$\alpha\times\text{(first element of $B$)}+\beta\times\text{(second element of $B$)}+\gamma\times\text{(third element of $B$)}.$$So, if you exchange the order the answer changes too.

Comment: thank you. i tried implementing this in the wayy i understood it and got the right answer. my approach for each element of $B'$ was $a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0=cx^2+bx+a \mapsto (a,b,c)=(a_0,a_1,a_2)$. this gave me the correct matrix. though i think i may have trouble remembering this later...